# Competing sets of tick marks on a matplotlib plot with annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given the following `matplotlib` snippet that uses `annotations`:

```
labels = ['Point-%d' %i for i in range(0,10)]
outMat = np.array([(-20 + 20*x + 20*np.sin(math.pi * 2 * x), -30 + x*30 + np.sin(math.pi * 2 * x)) for x in range(0,10)])
fig = plt.figure()
plt.title(title)
ax = fig.subplots(1,1)
for i in range(outMat.shape[0]):
  ax.annotate(labels[i],outMat[i],(outMat[i][0],outMat[i][1]))
plt.scatter(outMat[:,0],outMat[:,1])
fig.show()
```

We end up with **overlapping/competing** `y` and `x` tick labels:

The correctly scaled ticks from [0.0 to 250.0] - based on the range of the input `x` and `y` values- should be the *only* ones.  It is unclear why there are tick marks of [0.0-1.0] in 0.2 increments: the request here is to remove those spurious marks.

[image]

What needs to change in the snippet?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Moberg Updated the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you add a subplot to your figure, which adds another set of labels. You prevent this, by using only `plt.subplots`:

```
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
labels = ['Point-%d' %i for i in range(0,10)]
outMat = np.array([(-20 + 20*x + 20*np.sin(np.pi * 2 * x), -30 + x*30 + np.sin(np.pi * 2 * x)) for x in range(0,10)])
plt.scatter(outMat[:,0],outMat[:,1])
for i in range(outMat.shape[0]):
    ax.annotate(labels[i],outMat[i],(outMat[i][0],outMat[i][1]))
plt.title("title")
plt.show()
```

Comment: you beat me to it - by trial and error discovered `fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)` fixed this